# display check boxes value from database in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I am storing service_name array for my 9 check boxes. This is my code for checkboxes.

```
<?php           
  $service_name=get_post_meta($edit_id, 'service_name',true);
?>
<input type="checkbox" class="service_name" size="80" name="service_name[]" 
     value="architecture" 
<?php if(in_array('architecture',(array)$service_name)  ){
   echo "checked";
   } ?> 
  onclick='chkcontrol(0)';/>Architecture
```

Other checkboxes are same as it is. Now I want to display only selected checkboxes from database on another page. So how do I do that? chkcontrol is for limiting checkbox selection limit upto 3. I am getting correct values while editing also.

Comment: Can you show us the method by which you are saving this meta data ?

Comment: Yes I am saving service_name array in database in serialize format.

Comment: @Rikesh I get selected checkbox in form action page.